# 1 dimensional list to 2 dimensional list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, if-statement

How can I convert this

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
```

to this

```
list = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

I want to separate the objects to groups of three in each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should split any list into chunk of threes.

```
def chunks(l):
    return [l[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
```

If you want the longer version, here you go.

```
def chunks(l):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(l), 3):
        result.append(l[i:i + 3])
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the numpy reshape function, as so:

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'])
l.reshape(3,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

same as @Ian but make it list to answer the question

```
initial_state = [1,2,0,3,4,5,6,7,8]
l = np.array(initial_state)
ilist = l.reshape(3,3).tolist()
print(ilist)
```

```
[[1, 2, 0], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```